# How to Track the message in webaphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have question can we track the messages ( transaction) in websphere MQ, if yes how to enable the tracking in queue manager level.or is there any support pack for the same.

@Josh: Thanks for your replay

Recently we have faced the issue around 300 imps msgs are didn't received to my receiver application, so we have checked the queue manager status, queue cur-depth and checked is there any UNCOM msgs available in Queue level UNCOM is status is '0' channel status is running no error found in queue manager error logs with time stamp of issue.
and also we have checked with database team no information is available for the same.
for this situation we need to track the message so we can easily identify the issue.

@ Roger: can your please suggest me what are commercial product we have,so we can check with application owners for the same.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide more details on what you mean by track the messages?   What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could try activity trace.  If you want full message tracking then you need to look at the various commercial products (i.e. MQ Auditor).

Comment: FYI, putting @user in a question will not alert anyone.   You should respond in comments where @ user does alert someone.  The updates you want to edit in are logs or code,  not conversations.

Answer (score 0):

MsgId will be unique for every message sent out from queue manager.